# If an upper semicontinuous multivalued map is compact on a set, is it compact on the boundary as well?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, compact-operators, set-valued-analysis

I have stumbled upon the following problem during my research:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, $K\subset X$ nonempty, $F:\overline{K}\rightarrow 2^{Y}$ an upper semicontinuous multivalued map with nonempty, convex, compact values, that is compact on $K$ (in the operatorial sense). Prove that $F$ is also compact on $\overline{K}$.

This seems easy to prove, yet I'm stuck on the details, I think I'm not seeing the woods from the trees. If anybody could please help me out with the proof, it would be much appreciated. I might mention that I only need a weaker version of this statement (but I posted it this way, since it's easier to formulate, and my intuition tells me that this should be true as well), so if it makes the problem easier, we can also suppose that $K$ is a convex cone.

Thanks in advance.